# Overlap bug in Close Dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close, information-display

How about we fix this little bug in the Close dialog:

[image: Close Overlap Bug]

Comment: You seem to be having terrible luck with the overlap issues.

Comment: You said it, I see them all over, but this was the first time I saw this one, thought it might have to do with all the Close as Dupe changes.

Comment: No repro...On what side? What Browser? And you did not play with the zoom/font-sizes, did you?

Comment: Firefox 17.0.1, I'm sure the zoom is non-standard, can't really keep track of it anymore.  I'm getting overlap here right now on the comments and the Add Comment button.  I've surmised before it might be the DPI setting.  But all the other overlap has been horizontal, this is vertical.

Comment: Okay, I can repro the issue if I force a minimum-font-size in the content-settings (see Settings -> Content -> Font & Colors -> Advanced) (of 20+, that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was reported on Scifi.SE, and SE people responded already.  It will be fixed [in the next build](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/close-question-reasons-overflow-the-box).

So just wait patiently, I guess.