# Close dialog spacing is off

Tags: bug, user-interface, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [White-space in close dialogue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166152/white-space-in-close-dialogue)

Probably a result from [Overlap bug in Close Dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166136/overlap-bug-in-close-dialog), now the number of close votes you have remaining in the close vote dialog spacing looks way off when you've already voted to close a question (on latest FF release):

[image]

Comment: @Charles I think nickb is referring to the horizontal offset for the remaining votes, which is distinct from the gap between the last close reason and the remaining votes indicator.

Answer (score 1):

This looks even odder on Meta sites where the *not a real question* option is missing:

[image: Spaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaace]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is **intentional** now that the regression of

- [The "Vote to Close" button for duplicates is inefficiently placed and shouldn't move away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93170/195914)

[has been adressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates-is-inefficiently-placed-and-shouldnt#comment485771_93170)

> bit of extra whitespace on the close dialog now... Guess we'll need some new close reasons to pad it out.